# Colorbox for all Images in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, colorbox

I would like to use Colorbox with all of my images in my Wordpress Blog.
I am using this command to add the rel='colorbox' in my functions.php:

```
 //colorbox
  // adds the colorbox jQuery code
  function insert_colorbox_js() {
  ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      // <![CDATA[
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){
          $("a[rel='colorbox']").colorbox({
                  transition:'elastic', 
                  opacity:'0.7', 
                  maxHeight:'90%'
          });
          $("a[rel='colorboxvideo']").colorbox({
                  iframe:true, 
                  transition:'elastic', 
                  opacity:'0.7',
                  innerWidth:'60%', 
                  innerHeight:'80%'
          });
      });  
      // ]]>
      </script>
  <?php
  }
  add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_colorbox_js' );

  // automatically add colorbox rel attributes to embedded images
  function insert_colorbox_rel($content) {
    $pattern = '/<a(.*?)href="(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)"(.*?)>/i';
      $replacement = '<a$1href="$2.$3" rel=\'colorbox\'$4>';
    $content = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $content );
    return $content;
  }
  add_filter( 'the_content', 'insert_colorbox_rel' );
```

This function entry worked great on my local Mamp setup, but since I move the website to my server it's not working anymore - the rel attribute gets added to the img Tag instead the a link:

```
<div id="attachment_1131" class="wp-caption alignleft" style="width: 160px"><a href="http://www.somesite.net/somelink/" rel="attachment wp-att-1131"><img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-1131" title="Some title" src="http://www.somesite.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/CIMG0935-150x150.jpg" rel='colorbox' alt="Some Text" width="150" height="150" /></a><p class="wp-caption-text">Some other Text</p></div>
```

How do I have to change the functions.php to make it work again?

Thanks for any help!

BTW - I am on the latest Wordpress 3.4.2

Comment: I close the PHP Tag because of the Javascript - I open the Tag again after the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself - the default upload link was somehow changed in my theme. I had to add this line to the functions.php:

```
update_option('image_default_link_type' , 'file');
```

So, the function in the previous post works just fine...